# Multiple third party dependency versions

Tags: ios, swift

I work on a library that gets distributed as an XCFramework, this library depends on the lottie library https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios.

I have a client that also uses lottie in his app, but he wants to upgrade his lottie version to a newest one that is different from the one my library is using.

Is there a way to make that work? Or do the versions have to match?

I tried running the app with different versions and I run into compilation errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.